# How to add one array data into multiple dynamic arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array in javascript like

```
var arr = ["aa","bb","cc", "dd"];
```

and now I want to store these values into multiple arrays dynamically like

```
var arr1 = ["aa"];
var arr2 = ["bb"];
var arr3 = ["cc"];
var arr4 = ["dd"];
```

Here the as per the size of the "arr" array I need to create dynamic arrays to store those values. For example in "arr" I have 4 values then I need to create 4 dynamic arrays to store 4 values.

I dont have any idea how to achieve this any help?

Comment: 1) Is it about Java or JavaScript? 2) You know how to accept answers?

Comment: Seems Javascript, as I never saw `var` in Java.

Comment: @Nithin Kumar Reddy -- You've asked 11 questions but have not yet accepted **any** answers. You may want to work on that issue before asking any more questions.

Comment: It is in javascript only not in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing exactly what you are asking for is with eval. I don't suggest using it so I put together an object, which is close and preferred.

http://jsfiddle.net/P9SSA/1/

```
var myOneArray = ["a","b","c","d"];

var varPrefix = "arr";
var myObj = {};
for (var i = 1; i <= myOneArray.length; i++) {
     eval(varPrefix + i + '=["' + myOneArray[i-1] + '"]');
     myObj[varPrefix + i] = [myOneArray[i-1]];
}

document.write(arr1);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(myObj.arr3);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i got a solution

Answer (score 1):

In global scope you can do:

```
arr.forEach( function( value, index ) {
    window["arr"+(index+1)] = [value];
});
```

Inside arbitrary scope, this is only possible under non-strict eval:

```
var arr = ["aa","bb","cc", "dd"];

eval( arr.map( function( value,index) {
    value = typeof value == "string" ? '"' + value + '"' : value;
    return 'var arr'+(index+1)+' = ['+value+']';
}).join(";") + ";" );
```

Evaluates the following code:

```
var arr1 = ["aa"];
var arr2 = ["bb"];
var arr3 = ["cc"];
var arr4 = ["dd"];
```

[forEach shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
[map shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Why not use `for(var i = ...)`? Hint: MSIE.

Comment: @SalmanA because it allows the answer to be more meat and less boilerplate.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for your reply. i had tried with your approach it doesn't worked for me. can you provide some more code

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayOfArrays = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrayOfArrays[i] = [];
    arrayOfArrays[i].push(arr[i]); 
}
```